# Aspnet core 5.0 inject dependency in startup.cs constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add a parameter to the constructor of the Startup class in Asp.net core using this method: https://mattmazzola.medium.com/asp-net-core-injecting-custom-data-classes-into-startup-classs-constructor-and-configure-method-7cc146f00afb

However, this doesn't work for me.
Here's my C# Code:

```
public class AppAProgram
{
    #region Members
    private IHostBuilder hostBuilder;

    private IHost host;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public AppAProgram(string[] args)
    {
        this.hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        ILauncherContext launcherContext = new DummyLauncherContext();
        this.hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddSingleton<ILauncherContext>(launcherContext); });
        this.hostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<AppAStartup>(); });
        this.host = hostBuilder.Build();
    }
    #endregion

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppAProgram appAProgram = new AppAProgram(args);    
        appAProgram.Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.host.Run();
    }
}
```

Here's the constructor for which I add an injected parameter:

```
    #region Constructors
    public AppAStartup(IConfiguration configuration, ILauncherContext launcherContext)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        this.launcherContext = launcherContext;
    }
    #endregion
```

When I do this, I get this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Spike.Run.Launcher.ILauncherContext' while attempting to activate 'Spike.Run.AppA.AppAStartup'.'

Comment: while injecting dependencies into the Startup's constructor is something funny to play, do you have an actual reason why you want that? Any possible scenarios for that?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `services.AddSingleton<ILauncherContext,DummyLauncherContext>()` to add the dependency? Instead of creating the object yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [**The Startup class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-startup-class)

> Only the following service types can be injected into the Startup constructor when using the Generic Host (IHostBuilder):
>
> - IWebHostEnvironment
> - IHostEnvironment
> - IConfiguration
>
> ...
>
> **Most services are not available until the `Configure` method is called.**

***emphasis mine***

Use the `Configure` method instead

```
public AppAStartup(IConfiguration configuration) {
    Configuration = configuration;        
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ..., ILauncherContext launcherContext) {

    //access launcherContext here

    //...
}
```